# Mobile first. Media query not working on a specific div

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Im new in coding. I'm making my first website (mobile first). It were all fine, all divs working, responsive, all great! But now I added a new div(nothing special I guess) but when I try to just put a single code (even without media queries) it doesn't work in mobile version. Tablet and desktop are working correctly. I tried to modify other divs and they work fine too.

Here is the code.

HTML

```
<section class="flvcko-wear">
  <ul class="lista-articulos">
    <div class="articulo">
      <li>
        <img src="img/cap.png" alt="">
        <p>Flvcko cap</p>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</section
```

CSS

```
 .flvcko-wear ul{
          list-style-type: none;
        }
```

It doesn't even recognize the 'list-style-type:none;'

Answer (score 0):

It's probably caused by that weird HTML structure – `div` is not allowed as child of `ul` (try pasting your code into HTML validator).

This would make more sense:

```
<section class="flvcko-wear">
  <ul class="lista-articulos">
    <li>
      <div class="articulo">
        <img src="…" alt="…">
        <p>…</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Or even omitting the `div` altogether, since you can style `li`, too:

```
<section class="flvcko-wear">
  <ul class="lista-articulos">
    <li class="articulo">
        <img src="…" alt="…">
        <p>…</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Still not working :( Its very weird, even for me that I'm a beginner.

Comment: @LuisD'Andrea Maybe it's caused by some other part of your code, CSS scope/specificity can be a double-edged sword… I'll try to help you if you post more.

Comment: Yes, apparently there is something in my CSS that is wrong. Because when I pasted this code above other css it worked but the others stopped working. I would show you but I would need paste the whole code, I gues. Im completely lost!

Comment: And the thing that bugs me the most is that this problem is ONLY in mobile. When I resize to desktop all works normally, no matter the css position.

Comment: Solved! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great! What was the problem?

Comment: A bracket hahaha. Just begginer mistakes, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer, try eliminating the `div`. Try changing your code to the following:

**HTML:**

```
<section class="flvcko-wear">
   <ul class="lista-articulos">
       <li>
           <img src="img/cap.png" alt="">
           <p>Flvcko cap</p>
       </li>
   </ul>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul.lista-articulos {list-style-type: none;}
```